# How to bind an event to a ribbon button click in wxpython-phoenix

Tags: python, python-3.x, event-handling, wxpython, ribbon

I want to know how to use bind method with ribbon button in wxpython for python 3.4 (Phoenix version 3.0.3) because I tried all possible ways used with menus and buttons but all the time I have an error looks like:

File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\wx\core.py", line 1200, in _EvtHandler_Bind
    assert source is None or hasattr(source, 'GetId')
AssertionError

please help with simple example if possible. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem by using

```
import wx.ribbon as RB
```

instead of:

```
import wx.lib.agw.ribbon as RB
```

and bind with:

```
import wx
import wx.ribbon as RB
# Class code goes here...
self.ribbon = RB.RibbonBar(self,wx.NewId())
self.page_home = RB.RibbonPage(self.ribbon, wx.NewId(), "Home")
self.panel1 = RB.RibbonPanel(self.page_home, wx.ID_ANY, "Panel#1")
self.button_bar1 = RB.RibbonButtonBar(self.panel1)
bmp = wx.ArtProvider.GetBitmap(wx.ART_NEW, wx.ART_OTHER, wx.Size(32, 32))
self.button_bar1_Exit = self.button_bar1.AddButton(wx.ID_ANY, "Exit", bmp, 'Close Window')
self.button_bar1.Bind(RB.EVT_RIBBONBUTTONBAR_CLICKED, self.on_button_bar1)
def on_button_bar1(self, event):
    button = event.GetButton()
    if button == self.button_bar1_Exit:
        self.Close()
```

I will leave my answer which worked for me perfectly without accepting it for a while to give a chance for better idea, if not I will accept mine.

Comment: I am actually not very professional with wxpython, so as part of my question, can any one tell me what is the difference between

Comment: sorry, but I mean between 'wx.ribbon' and 'wx.lib.agw.ribbon'? and if it is necessary to put it in separate question, please tell me.

Comment: `wx.ribbon` is contains wrappers around the C++ ribbon classes. `wx.lib.agw.ribbon` contains an alternate implementation written only in Python code.  Typically things like this are mostly compatible with the wrapped C++ version, but they tend to be easier for Python developers to debug, extend with their own custom code, or etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind a specific event handler to each button if you assign an ID to them instead of using wx.ID_ANY. It's cleaner than having a large and growing if/elif/else block in a single event handler.

```
import wx
import wx.ribbon as RB

BUTTON_EXIT_ID = wx.NewId()

# Class code goes here...
self.ribbon = RB.RibbonBar(self,wx.NewId())
self.page_home = RB.RibbonPage(self.ribbon, wx.NewId(), "Home")
self.panel1 = RB.RibbonPanel(self.page_home, wx.ID_ANY, "Panel#1")
self.button_bar1 = RB.RibbonButtonBar(self.panel1)
bmp = wx.ArtProvider.GetBitmap(wx.ART_NEW, wx.ART_OTHER, wx.Size(32, 32))
self.button_bar1_Exit = self.button_bar1.AddButton(BUTTON_EXIT_ID, "Exit", bmp, 'Close Window')
self.button_bar1.Bind(RB.EVT_RIBBONBUTTONBAR_CLICKED, self.on_exit, id=BUTTON_EXIT_ID)

def on_exit(self, event):
    self.Close()
```